# Cordova application deploy on Windows Phone 8 fails with exit code 2

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to deploy a blank cordova app on Windows Phone 8 emulator using CLI but get the following error message when running the command cordova emulate wp8.

```
Deploying package to emulator
Error: Invalid target device specified.

ERROR: Error code 2147942487 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Xap Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe with args: /installlaunch,D:/MHIS/platforms/wp8/Bin/debug/CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap,/targetdevice:xd
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\sumits\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

What is the reason for this? I am able to deploy a blank app from Visual Studio on the emulator without any issues. I have the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK and Emulator installed as well.